# PC wont boot when graphics card plugged in

Tags: boot, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I recently got new motherboard/cpu/ram, though the PC wont boot at all when the gfx card is plugged in. Gfx card is still old and quite outdated so I was thinking maybe it is imcompatible?

PC components are:

- MSI X99S
- Intel i7-5820K with Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO
- 16gb Ballistix Sport
- Radeon 5770
- OCZ ModXStream Pro 600W (Did also try Corsair RM Series RM1000 1000W)

The issue seems to be linked to the graphics card as if I remove it all the fans spin correctly and everything seems fine. When I put the graphics card in the motherboard everything still seems fine, gfx and cpu fans spin pretty fast.

As soon as I plug in the power cord into the gfx card though then the CPU fan spins really slowly for a few seconds then stops, then spins slowly, ect. The graphics card does this too. Like I mentioned above, I tried a bigger psu assuming it could be a power related issue but this same problem still happens. I have tried putting the gfx card into my old machine and it still works fine there.

Any clue what components may be causing issues here? I dont have any other gfx cards around to test sadly. I was thinking of buying a new one but wanna make sure it is likely to be related to that.

Thanks

Comment: So the computer boots to Windows just fine without the GPU? Have you tried a different PCI-E Slot?

Comment: PC doesnt boot fine. I dont have a gfx card to test the display. The fans spin though like it seems like they should when the gfx card isnt plugged in. They dont spin properly when it is plugged in

Comment: I had that when two capacitors died by the video card slot. Obviously something is wrong with power. Perhaps the GPU itself is faulty? Try different PSU and GPU (if you get one).

Answer (score 0):

A few thing to try:  Do a Google search for whatever motherboard model you are using, and see if it finds anything about that motherboard being incompatible with the type of graphics card you are trying.  That's what kept one of my computers from booting with a new graphics card.  Also, check if a newer BIOS or UEFI is available for your computer; if so, that might make it more compatible with the graphics card.